# can we automate testing of .apk(Android) applications using UFT 12.0

Tags: testing, automation, qtp, functional-testing, hp-uft

I am testing a mobile application.
Can we automate the testing of the same using HP-Unified Functional Testing Version 12.0?

Answer (score 2):

For native application support (equivalent to context-sensitive support you have for desktop applications), you'll need to work with a 3rd Party Add-in like Perfecto Mobile.

Otherwise, you're option is to run the application in an emulator on the desktop or use remote software to replicate the device screen on your desktop.  Then you'd automate it like any other windows application, but you're not going to be able to see object.  Everything would be image-based.

Image-based testing is OK for very small automation tasks, but not much else.  Anything more complex and you'll quickly end up in a maintenance and playback reliability nightmare.  To do it right, you're going to need additional software that lets you interact with native objects in Android.

Comment: Happy to help.  If you found the suggestion addressed your question, please accept the answer so your question doesn't appear unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can automate testing of android (apk) using UFT 12. I am currently testing an android application using UFT with a .net Add-in using real devices.  All functions were created using c# and appium in Visual studio 2013 - c#.net. Then the objects are called from UFT using the .net dll.

Brief Example: 
Dim objTest, results

Set objTest = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("MyAndroidTest.MyAndroidTestClass","C:\automation\API\MyAndroidTest.dll")

results = objTest.MyEnrollment("name","password")

if results = ""
  ....set to false
else
 ...set to true
end if

Answer (score 0):

Do you hear about Mobile Center? I would suggest you to try out Mobile Center and UFT, and with latest version UFT 14.03.

It allows testing of all kinds of mobile apps, system apps, mobile browser, homemade native or hybrid app etc.

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.03/UFT_Help/Content/MC/mobile_on_UFT_setup.htm